# How to @SpringBootTest() a class that @DependsOn() another bean

Tags: spring-boot

I have a spring boot application with a class that @DependsOn another bean, like this:

```
@Configuration
public class SomeBeanConfig {
    @Bean
    public SomeClass someBean() { 
    ...

@DependsOn("someBean")
public class ClassIWantToTest { 
    ...

@SpringBootTest(classes = ClassIWantToTest.class)
public class TestForClassIWantToTest {
    @Resource private ClassIWantToTest foo;
    ...
```

The `"someBean"` dependecy works fine during normal application runs, but when running `TestForClassIWantToTest` I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
...
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 
'ClassIWantToTest': 'ClassIWantToTest' depends on missing bean 'someBean'; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:
No bean named 'someBean' available
```

How can I make a bean with name `"someBean"` and the right type available in the application context before Spring tries to instantiate `TestForClassIWantToTest`? (A mock bean is fine).

If I try to create it as a @MockBean in the test class:

```
@MockBean(name="someBean")
private SomeClass someBean;
```

I get this error instead

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not inject field: 
private somepackage.SomeClass somePackage.TestForClassIWantToTest.someBean 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: 
Bean named 'someBean' is expected to be of type 'somepackage.SomeClass' but was actually 
of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.support.NullBean'
```

Spring boot version 2.2.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there might be three ways to accomplish this:

1)

```
@Configuration
@Profile("test")
public class MyTestConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SomeClass someBean() {
        return new SomeClass();
   }
}
```

And then
`@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")` on your test. Or

2)

```
@TestConfiguration
public class MyTestConfiguration {
@Bean
public SomeClass someBean() {
    return new SomeClass();
  }
}
```

And then `@Import(MyTestConfiguration.class)` on your test. Or

3)
`@Import(SomeBeanConfig.class)` on your test should also work. It will import the entirety of the config tho which might not be what you want

This will create the necessary Bean and have it instantiated before your test runs. It will create a normal version of the Bean tho which might not what you want but your question did not specify